# Teaching Programming Best Practices to Perl Developers

Tags: perl

I have been delivering training on Programming Practices and on Writing Quality Code to participants who have been working on Java since sometime. Object Oriented Analysis and Design is the base and I cover S.O.L.I.D. Principles and excerpts from books like Clean Code, Code Complete 2 and so on.

I am scheduled to deliver training to Perl Programmers(with less than 1 yr. exp. in Perl) in two days and they do not use the Moose(an extension of the Perl 5 object system which brings modern object-oriented language features).

I am now confused as to how to structure my training as they don't follow OOPs.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Shardul.

Comment: Teach the core Perl language first, then teach the add-ons after they know the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the answers here are answers about teaching OOP to Perl programmers who don't use it, but your question sounds like you're stymied on how to teach a course on code quality, in light of the fact that your Perl programmers do not use OOP, not specifically that you want to teach OOP to non-OO programmers and force them into that paradigm.

That leaves us with two other paradigms of programming which Perl supports well enough:

1. Good ol' fashioned [*Structured* Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) also [*Modular* Programming](http://etutorials.org/Programming/perl+bioinformatics/Part+I+Object-Oriented+Programming+in+Perl/Chapter+1.+Modular+Programming+with+Perl/)
2. [Functional programming support in Perl](http://perl.plover.com/yak/fp/) (also [Higher-Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/))

I use both of these--combined with a *healthy* dose of objects, as well. So, I use objects for the same reason that I use good structure and modules and functional pipelines. Using the tool that brings order and sanity to the programming process. For example, object-oriented programming is the main form of polymorphism--but OOP is *not* polymorphism itself. Thus if you are writing idioms that assist in polymorphism, they assist in polymorphism, they don't have to be stuck in some ad-hoc library "class" and called like `UtilClass->meta_operator( $object )` which has *little* polymorphism itself.

[`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) is a *great* object language, but you don't call `Moose->has( attribute => is => 'rw', isa => 'object' )`. You call the *operator* `has`. The *power* of `Moose` lies in a library of *objects* that encapsulate the meta-operations on classes--but also in simple expressive operators that the rather open syntax of Perl allows. I would call that the appreciation of solving the problems that OOP solves with objects.

Also, I guess I have a problem with your problem, because "not OOP" is a big field. It can range from everything-in-the-mainline coding to not-*strictly*-OOP (where the *process* of programming is not simply OOP analysis). So I think you have to know your audience and know what it is they use to keep that code structured and sane. I can't imagine a *modern* Perl audience that isn't at least object-*users*.

From there, [Perl Best Practices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) (often abbreviated PBP) can help you. But so would learning that

- simply because OOP is one of the best supports for polymorphism it *isn't* polymorphism in itself
- simply because OOP is one of the best supports for encapsulation it *isn't* encapsulation in itself.
- That OOP has been assisted by structured and modular programming--and is not by itself those things. Some of its power is simply *just* those disciplines.

In addition, as big as an object author and consumer I am, OOP is *not* the way I think. *Reusability* is the way I think: What have I done before that I do not want to write again? What have I written that is similar? How can I make my current task just an *adapter* of what has been written before. (And often: how can I sneak my behavior branch an established module in a single line?)

As a result, a number of my constructs would *fail* the pedestrian goal of OOP. To give you a better view: I divide code into two "domains": Highly abstract and polymorphic *Library* code, and the *Scripting* that I need to do to get the *particular* function that I'm required in a current project. (this is essentially what "application" means, but I don't think it would be as clear). As a result, polymorphism is mainly instrumental in providing *adaptability*, but the adaptation itself is whatever takes the least lines of code. My optimum system would be a library that allows scripting/adaptation at any juncture between library behavior and a set of configurations or scripts that address a particular problem. Again, if I had my druthers, configuration would be injected from the scripted domain and no library code would say "I need a properties file" by itself, unless it was a library module encapsulating the algorithm of configuration instanced in properties files. It would just know that it needs "policies" (or decisions from the application domain) in order to fulfil its function.

Thus, my ideal application contains special purpose "objects", which conform to "roles" but where *classes* are useless overhead--except that the classes perform the behavior which allow injectable data and behavior. So some of my Perl "objects" violate OOP analysis, because they are simply encapsulations of one-off solutions, kind of like the push-pin (expando) JavaScript objects.

I will often (later) revise a special-purpose object and push it further back into the library domain as I find that I need to write something like this again. All objects in the library domain are just on some level of the spectrum of specified behavior. Also, I arrange "data networks" where there is a `Sourced` type of class that simply encapsulates the behavior of accessing data either in the object itself or another source object. This helps speed my solutions *immensely*, but I've never seen it addressed in any duck-cat-dog-car-truck OOP primer. Also *templating*--especially when combined with "data networks"--immensely useful in coding solutions in a half-dozen lines or a half-day of work.

So I guess I'm saying, to the extent that *you* only know OOP for structuring programming, you won't be able to appreciate how much some older, sound practices or other paradigms do for you--or how things that qualify as OOP can promote mediocre adaptability. (Besides *components* are far more current than "objects".) Encapsulation solves many problems, but it also promotes the lack of data where you need it. The idea is to get data where you need it so that your canned behavior can realize the specifics of the problem and operate on that.

- Reread some stuff on structured programming
- Read some stuff on functional programming (assuming that you're not already familiar with it.)

Also it's possible that even an established, "productive" Perl team is writing ... *crap*. If they are not OOP programmers because they are simply writing crap code, then by all means teach them OOP and if they lack even *structured programming* *shove both of them down their throats* (I have a hard time considering the label "professional", here).

Comment: wow...it looks like I can pick up a lot for the session just from this answer.

Comment: +1. I don't think your answer is likely to be very useful to someone who has to give a presentation in a day and a half, but it makes a lot of truly excellent points, and is likely to give a lot of mileage to anyone coming across this question with less strict time constraints. (Including the OP, hopefully, once (s)he's past this presentation.)

Comment: Oops. Needless to say, I posted my comment before seeing SB.'s reply. Never mind!

Comment: @ruakh I agree with you completely and the answer made me realize that I need to learn Functional Programming. I am missing so much.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Answer (score 12):

Even without Moose, object-oriented programming in Perl is quite possible, and very common. Many CPAN modules offer their functionality through an object-oriented API, even if many of these *also* offer a non–object-oriented API. (A good example of this duality is [IO::Compress::Zip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Zip.html).) Obviously the norms of object-oriented design in Perl are somewhat different from those in some languages — encapsulation is not enforced by the language, for example — but the overall principles and practices are the same.

And even without any sort of object-oriented programming, Moosish or otherwise, there's plenty to talk about in terms of laying out packages, organizing code into functions/subroutines/modules, structuring data, taking advantage of `use warnings` (or `-w`) and `use strict` and `-T` and CPAN modules, and so on.

I'd also recommend Mark Jason Dominus's book [*Higher-Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), which he has made available for free download. I don't know to what extent you can race through the whole book in a day and put together something useful in time for your presentation — functional programming is a bit of a paradigm-shift for someone who's not used to it (be it you, or the programmers you're presenting to!) — but you may find some useful things in there that you can use.

Comment: +1 for HOP and the idea to stress functional nature of Perl. While you **can** do regular OOP in Perl - in many ways better than in Java since Perl allows for more powerful/flexible patterns and easy reflection - the reason to use a language is ideally to utilize its unique strengths, and functional programming techniques are among the Perl's major unique strengths.

Answer (score 4):

Take a good look at ['Perl Best Practices'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596001738) by Damian Conway. It has lots of solid material in it, and you won't go far wrong taking his advice.

Be aware, though, that `Getopt::Clade` is only available as a placeholder package - it is vapourware, in other words.

Comment: See also "Object Oriented Perl" also by Damian. Plenty of pre-Moose OO Perl in there!

Comment: Perl Best Practices also has a lot of outdated material in it. There's many ways to go wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at what's covered in the "Modern Perl" book too:

http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/

As the others say - plenty to cover without Moose.

- Setting up modules/distros
- Testing and TAP
- Deployment with cpanm / cpan / local::lib
- Important changes 5.8 5.10 vs 5.12 vs 5.14, autodie etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perl programmers must know about Perl's weakly functional features, like list contexts, map, grep, etc.  A little functional style makes Perl infinitely more readable.

Perl programmers must also understand Perl's traditional OO features, especially modules, bless, and tie.  Make them write an object or maybe tie a Cache::Memcached object around a query or something.